# Qt 4 version of[replacement code for] Qt 5 QJSValue class?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qt4, qt5

I have a Qt 5 application which makes use of QJSValue. The application works well. Now I will need to port the code back to Qt 4 using `#if QT_VERSION < 0x050000 <do Qt 4 code here> #endif`. However since QJSValue is not available in Qt 4, the back-porting is not easy.  Is there an easy way to resolve this, such as by creating a Qt 4 version of QJSValue ? We can ignore the question why Qt 5 code should be ported back to Qt 4. Thanks!

Comment: QScriptValue, but the semantics are not equivalent. And yes: why in the world do you want to port code back to an **unsupported version** of Qt?

Comment: A simple answer is because some old devices do not support OpenGL (ES 2). So they have to use Qt 4.

Comment: So what? Qt 5 does not require OpenGL.

Comment: If you're porting only because of the QML engine, you can still use the QGraphicsScene-based engine in Qt 5 (the [QtDeclarative module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html#qtdeclarative-module-in-qt-5)). If you're a commercial user, you should also consider the software [Qt Quick 2D Renderer](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/01/22/introducing-the-qt-quick-2d-renderer/).

Comment: @peppe I've heard that by default Qt 5 requires OpenGL. There may be a way to build Qt 5 for a target device without using OpenGL, as you have confirmed. The problem is that, for various reasons, some customers want to stay with Qt 4. That's why they want Qt 5 features ported back to Qt 4.